# How to capture the first value in a publisher one way and the rest another way

Tags: swift, combine

I have a publisher where I want to handle receiving the first value one way, and receiving the rest another way. Currently I have the following:

```
let bar = foo
    .first()
    .sink { value in
    print("first value is \(value)")
}

let baz = foo
    .dropFirst()
    .sink { value in
        print("one of the rest is \(value)")
    }

foo.send(1)
foo.send(2)
foo.send(3)
foo.send(4)
foo.send(5)
foo.send(6)
```

This works. But it forces me to have two subscriptions, one for the first value, and another for the rest. Is there a clever way of combining the two into one subscription (without external flag management). Something like:

```
let bar = foo
    .first()
    .sink { value in
        print("first value is \(value)")
    }
    .dropFirst()
    .sink {
        print("the rest is \(value)")
    }
```

I'm aware the above doesn't make sense (and is probably uglier than the original solution) since a publisher is singular flow that doesn't branch (beyond value, completion, error), but that's due to my lack of creativity, I'm hoping someone here has something that I might be overlooking.

Comment: The usual thing is to map the value into a _tuple_ that says how to handle it.

Comment: from the publisher side?

Comment: As part of the pipeline. If you use something like `.scan` you know which is the first one and you can mark the tuple for special treatment.

Answer (score 1):

One typical approach is to use something like `.scan` to map into a tuple that tells the rest of the pipeline whether this is the first one or not.

In this simple example, the "rest of the pipeline" is simply `.sink`, but you can see that it does know which one is first.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var firstPassed = false
        subject
            .scan((0, false)) {prev, this in
                defer { firstPassed = true }
                return (this, firstPassed)
            }
            .sink {
                if !$0.1 {
                    print($0.0, "is the first one")
                } else {
                    print($0.0, "is not the first one")
                }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        subject.send(1)
        subject.send(2)
        subject.send(3)
        subject.send(4)
        subject.send(5)
    }
}
```

Result:

```
1 is the first one
2 is not the first one
3 is not the first one
4 is not the first one
5 is not the first one
```

Comment: Improved the example code so as not to rely on value assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

let foo = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
let first = foo
    .first()

let restOfFirst = foo
    .dropFirst()
    
Publishers.CombineLatest(first, restOfFirst) // <= here
    .sink {
        print("first value: \($0), rest Of other values\($1)")
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Resualt:

```swift
foo.send(1)
foo.send(2)
foo.send(3)
foo.send(4)
foo.send(5)
foo.send(6)

first value: 1, rest Of other values: 2
first value: 1, rest Of other values: 3
first value: 1, rest Of other values: 4
first value: 1, rest Of other values: 5
first value: 1, rest Of other values: 6
```